# Does $\sum\frac{2n^4-n-1}{n^6+n^4}(1-\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}))$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\frac{2n^4-n-1}{n^6+n^4}\left(1-\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\right)$$

My guess is that because the first part is equal to $\frac{1}{n^2}$ witch we know it converges and its multiplied by something that is between $0$ and $2$. I am not sure if i can say from this point that the whole series converges because the 2 series it consists of converge

Comment: Saying first part "is equal to" $1/n^2$ is not correct. Moreover the sequence $1-\sin(n\pi/2)$ oscillates among $0,1$ & $2$. So saying that it's series converges is incorrect as well. However a comparison can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As regards convergence, your observations lead to
$$0\leq \frac{2n^4-n-1}{n^6+n^4}\left(1-\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})\right)\leq \frac{2n^4}{n^6}\cdot 2=\frac{4}{n^2}.$$
What may we conclude?

P.S. The same works if we replace $\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2})$ with $\sin(a_n)$ where $(a_n)_n$ is any real sequence.

Comment: That $\frac{4}{n^2}$ converges so the original one converges. Thanks

Comment: Yes, where you apply the comparison test to a NON-NEGATIVE series.